# iOS Button Target Actions with Block Crashes

Tags: ios, crash, uibutton, action, block

I'm implementing UIButtons with block actions set on them for connivence and speed of integration. I've used this method before, a while ago now, and had little issue with it. Now, however, i'm facing an issue where integrating...

https://gist.github.com/2468899

... into my app now crashes it on launch. The error i'm receiving is as follows...

```
2012-09-27 22:18:47.459 flink[12174:907] -[UIButton setAction:withBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e8ae610
2012-09-27 22:18:47.460 flink[12174:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton setAction:withBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e8ae610'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x3885a3e7 0x333bf963 0x3885df31 0x3885c64d 0x387b4208 0xea477 0xff6af 0x36b92cb1 0x3882f8f7 0x3882f15d 0x3882df2f 0x387a123d 0x387a10c9 0x3868c33b 0x34014289 0xe7b8f 0xe7b30)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

... i've never seen this issue before but it's odd that it is immediately crashing without any interaction.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Have you verified category implementation is added to target? Cleaned / deleted derived data? Tried the objc / load_all flags?

Comment: I feel like such a noob. It didn't get added into my "compile sources" because the checkbox, somehow, became unticked by default.

Thanks Carl for pointing out what i should have seen :D

Comment: Did you remember to add the implementation file of that category to your target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must make sure to add the implementation file of the category to your target. In Xcode, go to the File Inspector and make sure the Target Membership checkbox for your target is checked.